# I want to store in an array messages from a ROS topic for further elaboration

Tags: c++, arrays, text, message, ros

I'm sorry if this question is too simple for you, but i don't have good programming skills and ROS knowledge. I have a ROS topic in which are published some numbers that are heart beat intervals in seconds. I need to subscribe to that topic and do this kind of elaboration: The idea is to have a little array of ten numbers in which i can store continuously ten heart beat. Then i have a bigger array of 60 numbers that must go up by ten position in order to have at the bottom the newest ten values of the small array and it has to "throw away" the ten oldest values ( i did a bit of research and maybe i have to use a vector instead of an array because in C++ array are fixed as far as i read ). Then i have to print every time these 60 values in a text file (i mean in a loop, so the the text file will be continuously overwritten). Moreover, i see that ROS outputs the data from a topic in this manner: `data: 0.987` with every data divided from the others by `---` in a column. What i really want, because i need it for a script that reads text file in this manner, is a text file in which the values are in one column without spaces and other signs or words, like this:

```
0.404
0.952
0.956
0.940
0.960
```

I provide below the code for my node, in which, for now, i did only the subscribing part, since i have no idea on how to do the things that i have to do later. Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "../include/heart_rate_monitor/wfdb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "writer");


ros::NodeHandle n;


ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/HeartRateInterval", 1000);


ros::spin();

return 0;
}
```

NOTE: I didn't include the Float32/64 header because i publish the heart beats as a string. I don't know if this is of interest.

EDIT: I will include below the code of the publisher node which publish on the ROS topic the data.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "../include/heart_rate_monitor/wfdb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "heart_rate_monitor");

ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/HeartRateInterval", 1000);

ros::Rate loop_rate(1);

while (ros::ok())

{ 

ifstream inputFile("/home/marco/Scrivania/marks.txt");

string line;

while (getline(inputFile, line)) {


istringstream ss(line);

string heart;

ss >> heart;

std_msgs::String msg;

msg.data = ss.str();

pub.publish(msg);

ros::spinOnce();

loop_rate.sleep();

}

}

return 0;

}
```

Since what is published is the "variable" `msg`, i tried to replace in the code given as an answer the variable `string_msg` with `msg`, but nothing has changed. Thank you!

Comment: Solved changing `==10` with `>=10` in the second if of the process_message function. Detailed explanation in the comment section of the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want but here is a brief example which might do what you need.

I'm using here an `std::deque` to have a circular buffer of 60 values. What you are missing in your code is a callback function `process_message` which is called for the subscriber every time a new message arrives.

I did not compile this code, so it may not compile right away but the basics are there.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include "../include/heart_rate_monitor/wfdb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>


static std::deque<std::string> queue_buffer;
static int entries_added_since_last_write = 0;

void write_data_to_file()
{
  // open file
  std::ofstream data_file("my_data_file.txt");
  if (data_file.is_open())
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < queue_buffer.size(); ++i)
    {
      data_file << queue_buffer[i] << std::end;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Error - Cannot open file." << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  data_file.close();
}

void process_message(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& string_msg)
{
  // if buffer has already 60 entries, throw away the oldest one
  if (queue_buffer.size() == 60)
  {
    queue_buffer.pop_front(); 
  }

  // add the new data at the end
  queue_buffer.push_back(string_msg.data);

  // check if 10 elements have been added and write to file if so
  entries_added_since_last_write++;
  if (entries_added_since_last_write == 10
      && queue_buffer.size() == 60)
  {
    // write data to file and reset counter
    write_data_to_file();
    entries_added_since_last_write = 0;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "writer");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/HeartRateInterval", 1000, process_message);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @cassinaj and for your effort! I'm sorry for the late answer, but i had two days off away from my PC. I tried to compiled it, but i had this error:  `/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor/src/scrittore.c‌ ​pp: In function ‘void process_message(const ConstPtr&)’: /home/marco/catkin_ws/src/heart_rate_monitor/src/scrittore.c‌​pp:46:37: error: ‘const ConstPtr’ has no member named ‘data’ queue_buffer.push_back(string_msg.data);`                                                        Do you have an idea why? I'm trying to seek it by myself anyway

Comment: Maybe the function `void process_message(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& string_msg)` it has only to have msg instead of string_msg? I found it in the publisher and subscriber tutorial. Anyway even if i change it i get almost the same error. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @Vtik thank you! Now it compiles! And it runs. But i cannot find the text file. Am i missing something?

Comment: std::ofstream data_file("my_data_file.txt"); change this line to whatever path and name you need.

Comment: @Vtik I tried it, I created an empty text file with a name of my choice but no data are written in it. Maybe I was not clear, but, what I want, is a text file as the output, not the input. The inputs are the ROS topic messages. Maybe with this code the program searches for a text file as the input? I don't understand. Thank you very much.. To both of you!

Comment: Ok, if i move the line `std::ofstream data_file("my_data_file.txt");` out of the function and i put it under or above the two `static` declarations, i'm able to create the file. But, as before, no data are written into it when i quit the ROS nodes and make a check on the file.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code of the publisher, if this can help.

Comment: UPDATE: I solved the problem! The program didn't enter in the second if of the process_message function because in the beginning the buffer of 60 numbers was empty and the double condition would never become true. So i simply changed the ==10 with >=10. Thank you guys for all your help!!